# How to use CDN in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, cdn, staticresource

I want to use CDN to serve static content like CSS, JavaScript and images in a project created with Spring MVC. But I didn't how to do it.

I'm new to Spring and I have seen some posts on the web:

- [JSP/Spring MVC and CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915975/jsp-spring-mvc-and-cdn)
- [How to use property from property file specified in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933862/how-to-use-property-from-property-file-specified-in-propertyplaceholderconfigure)
- [How to show values from property file in JSP in a spring MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111260/how-to-show-values-from-property-file-in-jsp-in-a-spring-mvc-app)
- http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/11/serving-static-resources-with-spring-mvc.html

But they didn't explain how to implement it.

For example:

In the past, I use `<c:url>` tags:

```
<img src="<c:url value="/path/to/image" />" alt="desc" />
```

When I use CDN, I may use following code:

```
<img src="${env.cdnUrl}/mypath/pic.jpg" />
```

But where should I put `${env.cdnUrl}`(in `web.xml` or `dispatcher-servlet.xml`(the configuration of Spring MVC))? And how to get the parameter in JSP?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: you can do request.setAttribute("env.cdnUrl", <value>) in the controller.

Comment: @anuraggupta But I have to declare it in every controller.

Comment: create a filter and add there; let all controllers passes through them

Comment: @anuraggupta You means use AOP? Any simpler method?

Comment: no not AOP, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-writing-filters.htm

Comment: okay, you can also set the env.cdnUrl in .properties file if configured and access the same.

Comment: @anuraggupta In which property file? Can you tell me more about it? Thanks.

Comment: does you applicationcontext file uses any properties file . example usage is http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented CDN service in Spring using following steps:

**Add following lines in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (Your Spring Configuration)**

```
<util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" location="classpath:/app.properties"/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer" />
```

Of course, you need to add DOM for `spring-util` at the top of the file:

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd"
```

**Setup in `app.properties`**

```
cdn.url=//cdn.domain.com/path/to/static/content
```

**Use CDN in JSP files**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('cdn.url')" var="cdnUrl" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cdnUrl}/css/semantic.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${cdnUrl}/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you can get more information in my [blog post](http://infinitescript.com/2015/04/use-cdn-service-in-spring-mvc/).

Answer (score 0):

approaches summarized:

1. use request.setAttribute("env", ) in controller and access the same in jsp.
2. create a servlet filter and do the same activity described above.
3. write the env value to properties file and try to access that in jsp pages. if using  InternalResourceViewResolver then exposedContextBeanNames can help with exposing properties in jsp.

   ```
   <bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
   <property name="locations">
   <list><value>property_file</value></list>
   </property>
   </bean>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
   <property name="viewClass"     value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/> 
   <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/> 
   <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
       <list>  
           <value>properties</value> 
       </list>
   </property>  
   </bean>
   ```

and access the values in jsp as ${properties.env}

Comment: Here's my PropertiesFactoryBean `<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
     <property name="locations">
         <list>
          <value>classpath:/app.properties</value>
         </list>
     </property>
 </bean>` After change to this, I can't access value in Spring configuration files.

Comment: did you added exposedContextBeanNames in viewResolver as well ?

Comment: Yes. And I didn't test whether it works or not in JSP. Because I can't load the properties from the properties file in Spring config. The application failed to load.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${properties.jdbc.driverClassName}

Comment: if in a properties file you have "jdbc.driverClassName" as key then write ${jdbc.driverClassName}

Comment: Still not working: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${jdbc.driverClassName}`. And I'm sure I have `jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in configuration file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71745/discussion-between-anurag-gupta-and-howard-shieh).

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this via an interceptor.

```
  <mvc:interceptors>
            <!-- path interceptor adds servlet path as an attribute -->
        <bean class="com.test.myInterceptor" />
```

Then in the interceptor code, you can have the attribute be set

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, 
 final HttpServletResponse response, 
  final Object handler) {
 // set the attribute for URL
```